# Wrap a secret key with a public key using PKCS#11

Tags: cryptography, pkcs#11

In my C program, I generate a public/private key pair with the function `C_GenerateKeyPair` and a sensitive (secret) key with `C_GenerateKey`. The aim is to wrap the secret key with the public key, but when I call the function `C_WrapKey`, I get the error **CKR_KEY_TYPE_INCONSISTENT**. The code runs if I use another wrapping secret key with attributes Wrap and Encrypt set.
The template used for the public key is the one proposed in PKCS#11 documentation:

```
CK_SESSION_HANDLE hSession;
CK_OBJECT_HANDLE hPublicKey, hPrivateKey;
CK_MECHANISM mechanism = {
   CKM_RSA_PKCS_KEY_PAIR_GEN, NULL_PTR, 0
};
CK_ULONG modulusBits = 768;
CK_BYTE publicExponent[] = { 3 };
CK_BYTE id[] = {123};
CK_BBOOL true = CK_TRUE;
CK_ATTRIBUTE publicKeyTemplate[] = {
   {CKA_ENCRYPT, &true, sizeof(true)},
   {CKA_VERIFY, &true, sizeof(true)},
   {CKA_WRAP, &true, sizeof(true)},
   {CKA_MODULUS_BITS, &modulusBits, sizeof(modulusBits)},
   {CKA_PUBLIC_EXPONENT, publicExponent, sizeof(publicExponent)}
};
```

The Wrap and Encrypt attribute are correctly specified, while for the secret key to be wrapped I add the attribute CKA_EXTRACTABLE. 
Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: In short, how to wrap a secret key using a public key.

Comment: Which PKCS#11 token are you using? What is the mechanism of the RSA key? Have you tried dropping the CKA_VERIFY attribute? It could also be tat your token only supports symmetric wrapping, and not asymmetric wrapping.

Comment: I'm using SafeNet eToken. The CKA_VERIFY can be dropped, but again I get the same error. Asymmetric wrapping was performed with CryptoAPI without errors.

Comment: Which eToken? Are you sure it supports RSA key wrap? Not all PKCS#11 tokens are created equal. This one seems to mainly focus on authentication.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error CKR_KEY_TYPE_INCONSISTENT is due to a wrong CK_MECHANISM, used in the function C_WrapKey. If we want to wrap a secret key with a RSA public key, set the following mechanism:

```
CK_MECHANISM dec_mec = {CKM_RSA_PKCS, NULL_PTR, 0};
```

Comment: I need to wrap a private RSA key with a secret key, can you help me in this?