# How to upload public RSA key to HSM (using PKCS#11 library)?

Tags: encryption, cryptography, pkcs#11, hsm

I am quite new to using PKCS#11 library so maybe someone with more experience can clear things up.

I want to do the following:

1. upload to HSM existing RSA public key (which was generated on PC)
2. and later use this uploaded key to wrap symmetric key that was generated on HSM.

I know how to generate symmetric key, but how to upload existing RSA public key?

Is this even possible using PKCS#11 library?

There seems to be similar question at [Wrap a secret key with a public key using PKCS#11](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18855249/wrap-a-secret-key-with-a-public-key-using-pkcs11) but it uses RSA key pair that is generated on HSM. I need to upload RSA public key to HSM myself.

Comment: Yes, of course, this is possible. You create a new object of type "public key". Details depend on what API you are trying to use.

Comment: But can we really state that an arbitrary HSM allows public key import?

Comment: API is PKCS#11. Which API method let's you create this public key? GenerateKey?

Comment: @EugeneMayevski'AlliedBits Which API are you referring to, if any? I can't figure out how to do this. Is there a standard API call?

Comment: @JonasJnz Did you ever figure this out?

Comment: @Anthony I was referring to higher-level APIs. If you call PKCS#11 directly, it's one API and you have functions there to create a new public object. If you use .Java or .NET, then you have different high-level APIs, via which you work with PKCS#11. In SecureBlackbox (we maintain this product) we have high-level classes that work with PKCS#11 under the hood, and offer you the convenient ways to use cryptographic hardware regardless of the platform (SecureBlackbox supports Java, .NET, C++ and more).

Comment: @EugeneMayevski'AlliedBits I'm working directly with a C API through the cryptoki library provided by Gemalto. I've been trying to import a public RSA key so I can wrap keys off of an HSM and then view the keys in plaintext, but nothing I've tried has worked. Are you saying that type of thing needs to use c_CreateObject? Their documentation does not seem to suggest that, but their documentation is also very bad, so maybe that's the right call. I can't figure out how to import the public RSA key or use it to encrypt an AES key generated on the HSM.

Answer (score 2):

We can use C_CreateObject function of PKCS#11 to import a public key to HSM.
This can be found from

[RSA PKCS#11](https://www.cryptsoft.com/pkcs11doc/v220/)
Functions -> Object Management Functions -> C_CreateObject

There is also an example of load public key. But it requires the **support of token** to load the public key from cryptoki library.

```
CK_SESSION_HANDLE hSession;
CK_OBJECT_HANDLE hKey;
CK_OBJECT_CLASS keyClass = CKO_PUBLIC_KEY;
CK_KEY_TYPE keyType = CKK_RSA;
CK_BYTE modulus[] = {... };
CK_BYTE exponent[] = {... };
CK_ATTRIBUTE keyTemplate[] = {
    {CKA_CLASS, &keyClass, sizeof(keyClass)}
    ,
    {CKA_KEY_TYPE, &keyType, sizeof(keyType)}
    ,
    {CKA_WRAP, &true, sizeof(true)}
    ,
    {CKA_MODULUS, modulus, sizeof(modulus)}
    ,
    {CKA_PUBLIC_EXPONENT, exponent, sizeof(exponent)}
};

CK_RV rv;

/* Create an RSA public key object */
rv = C_CreateObject(hSession, &keyTemplate, 5, &hKey);
if (rv == CKR_OK) {
.
.
}
```